# Real world objects and digital contents represented in RDF

Tags: linked-data, rdf

Not sure if this is the appropriate forum for this question, especially after the Dataversity Q&A site shutdown, so please feel free to suggest better avenues.

I am implementing an [LDP](https://www.w3.org/TR/ldp/) server and setting some semantic guidelines around it. One convention I want to encourage is the use of [Cool URIs](https://www.w3.org/TR/cooluris/) to separate the concept of Real World Objects (RWO) and the RDF documents about them.

So, if I request `http://server.org/ldp/rwo01` I would get the following (pseudo-)RDF:

```
# Information about the document describing the RWO
</rwo01> a ldp:Resource ;
  dcterms:created "2018-05-02"^^xsd:date .

# Information about the object itself
</rwo01#this> a myns:GreekAmphor ;
  dcterms:created "500 BC"^^xsd:string .
```

This looks pretty straightforward with physical objects. What about digital documents, e.g. a digital image? Retrieving `http://server.org/img01` (with content negotiation that yields the RDF documetn instead of the image contents) would give me:

```
# Information about the document describing the image
</img01> a ldp:Resource ;
  dcterms:created "2018-05-02"^^xsd:date .

# Information about the digital image itself
</img01#this> a myns:StillImage ;
  premis:hasSize "2469235"^^xsd:long ;
  dcterms:created "2010-10-21"^^xsd:date .
```

This is also fine, however a bit awkward. In fact, the URI matching exactly my request is the subject of the metadata about the document, not of the document itself which is most likely the first thing that I would be looking for.

If I subverted the suggestions in the Cool URIs document I would end up with more intuitive semantics:

Retrieving `http://server.org/img01`:

```
# Information about the digital image itself
</img01> a myns:StillImage ;
  premis:hasSize "2469235"^^xsd:long ;
  dcterms:created "2010-10-21"^^xsd:date .

# Information about the document describing the image
</img01#metadata> a ldp:Resource ;
  dcterms:created "2018-05-02"^^xsd:date .
```

And, to be consistent with this pattern, at this point I would have to turn the RWO representation upside down too:

Retrieving `http://server.org/rwo01`:

```
# Information about the object itself
</rwo01> a myns:GreekAmphor ;
  dcterms:created "500 BC"^^xsd:string .

# Information about the document describing the RWO
</rwo01#metadata> a ldp:Resource ;
  dcterms:created "2018-05-02"^^xsd:date .
```

Does that sound reasonable? Or am I reinventing the wheel? Or am I trying to invent a concave wheel?

Comment: There is the 'linked-data-platform' tag on SO. Example 10 from the LDP 1.0 Primer looks related.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on SO. 
I think that example #10 in the LDP primer deals with pure RDF, however examples #14 and #15 are closer to the topic. There, the metadata about the non-RDF document (`/alice/avatar/meta`) are stored as a child of the non-RDF content (`/alice/avatar`).

Comment: *however examples #14 and #15 are closer to the topic* -- as well as I understand, your `</img01>` is not LDP-NR...